# How to programmatically determine character dimensions of my terminal window?

Tags: perl, bash, scripting, terminal, terminal-emulator

I am writing a script which will display a stock chart as ASCII art in a terminal emulator window.  I normally use OSX/Terminal.app but a Linux-based solution would be an acceptable alternative.

My script currently has command-line args for screen width and height (again, as measured in CHARACTERS, not pixels), with defaults determined by environment variables of my own invention.  I would like these scripts to determine the current window's size (IN CHARACTERS), and use THAT as the default.  A typical size for a big window on my 17-inch Macbook Pro might be 200 x 68.

This is a perl script, but if you know a solution in some other language, do tell!

TIA.
Ken

Comment: Have you tried googling for "getting terminal size in perl"?

Comment: I tried other similar phrases but not that one ... That one indeed reveals the perl-ish solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way to do this is `tput lines` and `tput cols`; this queries, in order:

- `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` environment variables;
- `termios` settings, which are set by terminal emulators when you resize their windows;
- the `terminfo` description identified by `$TERM`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, geekosaur!  I actually prefer this solution over the more perl-ish solution using Term::ReadKey because it is a solution I can use both in perl scripts and in bash scripts.  I write tons of both kinds of scripts.

Comment: perl:  chomp(my $window_size_lines = `tput lines`);  # likewise for cols

Comment: tput lines was supposed to be in backticks.  I guess I haven't learned how to post code fragments in a reply.  I did it in my question using HTML <pre> tag.  Doesn't work here.

Comment: Use two backticks for quoting.  (hm, right, can't do displays in comments) ``this `has` backticks``

Comment: ``chomp(my $window_size_lines = `tput lines`);``   ... testing my new knowledge ... thanks!

Comment: this enabled me to use `tput reset` to 'fix' my screwed-up terminal settings very quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

From C, you'd use the `TIOCGWINSZ` option to an `ioctl` system call on `/dev/tty`.

This is exposed by the `Term::ReadKey` module - from `man perlfaq8`:

> **How do I get the screen size?**
>
> If you have `Term::ReadKey` module installed from CPAN, you can use it to fetch the width and height in characters and in pixels:
>
> ```
> use Term::ReadKey;
> ($wchar, $hchar, $wpixels, $hpixels) = GetTerminalSize();
> ```

Comment: I feel guilty not giving you the "accepted solution" trophy, because, as stated, yours is the best solution.  (Calling bash commands from perl is frowned upon, I know.  I frown too.)  What I didn't say in question is that I also do a lot of bash scripting, so the bash 'tput' command is actually more widely useful to me.  Sorry, whichever way I go, I won't be able to sleep at night.  :)

Comment: so you should - feel free to use tput from bash but you really should use the Term::ReadKey method when you're in a perl script instead of forking two extra commands ;-)  p.s. you might also want to investigate catching the SIGWINCH signal, which is sent anytime the terminal window gets resized.

Answer (score 1):

When run interactively, bash defines `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS`. Otherwise, use curses/ncurses to retrieve the terminal dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for prompt and helpful response!  To my dismay, I was unable to come up with a way to access $LINES and $COLUMNS from perl.  It is NOT an environment variable, though it is available from an interactive bash shell.  I actually wrote a window-size.c program using ncurses, and that would have been an acceptable solution.  Thanks again.